# How can I filter a page using drop down selection?

Tags: php, filter, html

I have a web page that displays a list of people and their nationality.

```
<td><?php echo $row['First_Name'] . " " . $row['Last_Name'] ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row['Country'] ?></td>
```

I would like to add a control to the page that allows the user to apply a filter on the country.

Any suggestions on how I should go about it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what part you need help with?  The server side, the Javascript, the whole thing, etc...

Comment: I'm using code like this to get the recordset:
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
  if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect to mysql server');
  }

  mysql_select_db("thepoolscene", $con);

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblPlayers");

There is a field in the table "Country".  I would like to filter the players using that field...

Answer (score 0):

You could make a link to the country - for instance like this:

```
//Change it, so it fits for your purpose    
<a href="file.php?filter=country">Filter by country</a>.
```

And the PHP could simply look like this:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass"); 
if (!$con) { 
    die('Could not connect to mysql server');
} 
mysql_select_db("thepoolscene", $con); 

$filterBy = ( isset( $_GET['filter']) ? 'country' : 'ASC');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblPlayers ORDER BY $filterBy");

?>
```